# To find max occurring letter in a given word

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

```
Input = 'RaamKuumabbbb'
Output = b
```

b appeared four times in the string A='RaamKuumabbbb'

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) first and then learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Does case matter?

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/495758/edit) and show us what you tried so far.

Comment: Similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168379/117549

Answer (score 1):

if your word is in a file say text.txt  then you can use

```
  sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' text.txt | sort| uniq -c | sort -nr  |  head -n 1
```

It will add new line between each character then will removes duplicates, and will sort them in descending order and will give you first entry i.e.  the max occurrence.

Or you can use:

```
echo "RaamKuumabbbb" | sed -E 's/(.)/\1\n/g' | sort |  uniq -c | sort -nr  |  head -n 1
```

Above both commands will give output as `4 b`, if you want only `b` as output then add pipe output to `awk '{ print $2 }'` i.e.:

```
echo "RaamKuumabbbb" | sed -E 's/(.)/\1\n/g' | sort|  uniq -c | sort -nr  |  head -n 1 | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 Input='RaamKuumabbbb'
 output=(`echo $Input | grep -o . | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n1`)

 echo ${output[1]} appeared ${output[0]} times in the string $Input
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl:

```
$ echo 'RaamKuumabbbb' | perl -pe 'map{$c{$_}++}split(//,$_);$_=[sort{$c{$b}<=>$c{$a}}keys(%c)]->[0]'
b
```

(no newline at end of output)

This uses Perl to count the number of occurrences of each character in the given string, and then sort the resulting hash by occurrences in decreasing order, extracting the most common character.

The Perl script, after a bit of tidying up:

```
# split string ($_) into individual characters
# count the number of occurrences of each in the hash %c
map { $c{$_}++ } split( //, $_ );

# sort the keys of %c (the characters) by 
# decreasing number of occurrences (the values)
# and pick out the first key
$_ = [ sort { $c{$b} <=> $c{$a} } keys(%c) ]->[0];
```

The `-p` option would prompt the Perl to output whatever is in `$_` after the execution of the code.

To get the count of each character:

```
$ echo 'RaamKuumabbbb' | perl -pe 'chomp;map{$c{$_}++}split(//,$_);$_=join "\n",map{"$c{$_}:$_"}sort{$c{$b}<=>$c{$a}}keys(%c)'
4:b
3:a
2:m
2:u
1:R
1:K
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo  RaamKuumabbbb  |
perl -lpe '
  $h{$_}++ for /./g;
  ($_) = reverse map { $h{$_} > $m and ($m,$i)=($h{$_},$_);$i } keys %h;
'
```

Alternatively, we can use the reverse numeric sort on the values of `%h` and grab the highest value in `$_`:

```
perl -lpe '
  $h{$_}++ for /./g;
  ($_) = sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a} } keys %h;
'
```

Working :

- First populate a hash %h, whose keys are the individual characters in the input string, which are obtained via the regex `/./g` and values are the count of the time a character is sen in the input string.
- Then we iterate over the keys of the hash, which are the individual unique characters in the string. On each iteration, we try to find  the maximum of the count and record it's character.
- The last character is stored in the $_, which is then implicitly taken to `stdout`.